# Thunderbird 3.0 - How do I recover some lost function?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I've just switched to Thunderbird 3.0. It's good, but please help me to fix some slight annoyances:

1. How do I turn off the message preview pane as default? I can turn it off from the View menu, or (sometimes) with F8, but I simply *don't want it*.
2. What happened to CTRL-Q as a shortcut for File->Exit? I still use multiple windows, so ALT-F4 doesn't do what I want and I have to go fiddling with the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Autohotkey to provide this function:

```
GroupAdd TBird, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass, , , ^$|Mozilla Firefox$ 
...
#If WinActive("ahk_group TBird") 
    ^q::WinClose, ahk_group TBird
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of Ctrl-Q, use Ctrl-W which appears to be a fairly widespread key combination for "close window." Not sure the origin, but I suspect it's related to cross-platform applications. The same combination works for closing tabs in Firefox, Notepad++ and IE8.

As far as the preview window/message pane, for me it retains the setting it had when I closed Thunderbird previously - if open, it's open, if closed it's closed. I've noted that F8 doesn't always work for me though - sometimes I have to select it from the View menu.

Comment: Thanks, fencepost. Unfortunately, CTRL-W is like ALT-F4 - it only closes the current window, not the whole app.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. There are some addons for customizing the keyboard, but I'm not sure if any of them are up to 3.1 yet.

Comment: Otherwise, "Alt-F, X" is probably your best bet.

Comment: 'Fraid I've found an even better one: gone back to 2.0.

In any event, thank you for trying to help (+1)